# MacOS Bash script - Escape string with Japanese characters

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I try to use the `printf %q` trick to add escape sequences to a Japanese filename in a shell script:

```sh
printf '%q\n'  "Toru Watanabe - 約束 ( 1982 )"
```

But the result is this:

```
$'Toru Watanabe - ?\204?\235\237 ( 1982 )'
```

Is there a trick for adding escape sequences in a shell script but leave those characters intact?

Edit: Locale info

```
LANG="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Solution: After the suggestion from tripleee I built bash 5.0 from source and it works. Thank you!

Comment: Most likely a problem w/ your terminal emulator or your locale ... your printf works as designed for me.  `Toru\ Watanabe\ -\ 約束\ \(\ 1982\ \)`

Comment: It could aso be a Bash version difference.

Comment: If I use %s instead of %q it looks normal but has no escape sequences.

Comment: Ok, I shall be honest: I'm in a MacOSX Sierra shell.

Comment: ...or locale version difference. on bash5 I get same as tink. `I'm in a MacOSX` and most probably you have bash3. Update.

Comment: On my Mac: Your command doesn't work in `iterm2`, using the default `Terminal` app from MacOs, it shows the expected result: `Toru\ Watanabe\ -\ 約束\ \(\ 1982\ \)`. Guess the issue is the Terminal app vs locale.

Comment: I use the Terminal app I think. /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal  Version 2.7.3 (388.1.1)

Comment: Could I fix the locales myself?

Comment: Probably yes. Perhaps [edit] once more to show the output of `locale`.

Comment: Added locale info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On MacOS out of the box (Bash 3.2.57(1)-release) I get the same output as you report, regardless of locale.

In a fresh Ubuntu Docker (Ubuntu 20.04 - Bash 5.0.17(1)-release), I still get

```
$'Toru Watanabe - \347\264\204\346\235\237 ( 1982 )'
```

with the default POSIX locale. After installing and activating the `de_DE.UTF-8` locale, I get the expected output.

```
# printf '%q\n'  "Toru Watanabe - \347\264\204\346\235\237 ( 1982 )"
$'Toru Watanabe - \347\264\204\346\235\237 ( 1982 )'

# apt-get update; apt-get install -y locales; dpkg-reconfigure locales
# # (... select de_DE.UTF-8 to be generated and installed as the default)

# export LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8

# printf '%q\n'  "Toru Watanabe - \347\346 ( 1982 )"
Toru\ Watanabe\ -\ 約束\ \(\ 1982\ \)
```

So I conclude that this is both locale-dependent and version-dependent.

I do believe that this is just an aesthetic problem, though. The octal escape codes in some sense are a better and more robust result than the raw kanji characters, because those will only work as long as the system is correctly set up for UTF-8. (But perhaps that's a reasonable assumption in this day and age, as long as you are not on Windows.)